# C# .net How to rename/change the spacecolor name in the pdf

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

i want to add the suffix such as "_KM001" in the color name of a pdf,pls look at the img of the pdf object struct.How to find the ColorSpace object? And How to find this /Separation array? And I want to change the color name of "PANTONE Cool Gray 10 C"and "Black"?The result of the color name is "Cool Gray 10 C_KM001"and "Black_KM001".Thanks all bosses.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPRPb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to SO,

You tagged your question as 'itext' and what you are asking for can probably be done with itext, but it requires in-depth knowledge of the PDF-Specification ISO32000 and a good understanding of the low-level itext functions.

I am proposing a simpler, more pragmatic approach that you can do with c# only and a free command line tool.

1. uncompress your PDF with [PDFtk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/)  this gives you a text-like file with most internal PDF objects in human readable form

> ```
> pdftk in.pdf output out.pdf uncompress
> ```

You did not provide a sample PDF, so I used one of my own that has Pantone/Spot colors. File out.pdf viewed in a Text editor will have the PDF Objects structured with
object number, generation number (0) obj - followed by the object contents.

> ```
> 74 0 obj [/Separation /PANTONE#20100#20CV /DeviceCMYK 
> <<
> /FunctionType 2
> /N 1
> /Range [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
> /C1 [0 0 0.50999 0]
> /Domain [0 1]
> /C0 [0 0 0 0]
> >>]
> endobj 
> 73 0 obj [/Separation /PANTONE#20101#20CV /DeviceCMYK 
> <<
> /FunctionType 2
> /N 1
> /Range [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
> /C1 [0 0 0.78999 0]
> /Domain [0 1]
> /C0 [0 0 0 0]
> >>]
> endobj 
> 72 0 obj [/Separation /PANTONE#20102#20CV /DeviceCMYK 
> <<
> /FunctionType 2
> /N 1
> /Range [0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1]
> /C1 [0 0 1 0]
> /Domain [0 1]
> /C0 [0 0 0 0]
> >>]
> endobj
> ```

2. Next parse the text file using standard c#, line by line and look for the string

> [/Seperation

that is NOT followed by /All. Those are your spot colors. Rename per code as you wish and write out a new file with the same encoding as the original, probably UTF8. Ensure you preserve binary sections otherwise you will destroy your pdf.

3. Final step is to make a valid PDF. Changing PDF content manually like this will throw off the XREF (object) locations which must be rebuild. It could be done manually as well, but it is too much work. It is just easier to run this shell command via a c# process.

> pdftk in.pdf output out.pdf compress

The result is a valid PDF with the Spot color renamed.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the PDF library you are using.

The code below shows how to accomplish this task using [PDF4NET](https://www.o2sol.com/pdf4net/overview.htm) library:

```
public static void SetColorantNameSuffix(string inputFileName, string outputFileName, string[] colorantNamesToReplace, string suffix)
{
    PDFFixedDocument document = new PDFFixedDocument(inputFileName);
    for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
        PDFCosDictionary resourcesDictionary = document.Pages[i].CosDictionary[PDFNames.Resources] as PDFCosDictionary;
        if (resourcesDictionary != null)
        {
            SetColorspaceNameSuffixInResources(resourcesDictionary, colorantNamesToReplace, suffix);
        }
    }
    document.Save(outputFileName);
}

private static void SetColorspaceNameSuffixInResources(PDFCosDictionary resourcesDictionary, string[] colorantNamesToReplace, string suffix)
{
    PDFCosDictionary colorspaceResourcesDictionary = resourcesDictionary[PDFNames.ColorSpace] as PDFCosDictionary;
    if (colorspaceResourcesDictionary != null)
    {
        string[] csIDs = colorspaceResourcesDictionary.Keys;
        foreach (string csID in csIDs)
        {
            PDFCosArray csArray = colorspaceResourcesDictionary[csID] as PDFCosArray;
            if ((csArray != null) && (csArray.Length == 4))
            {
                PDFCosName csName = csArray[0] as PDFCosName;
                if (PDFNames.Separation.Equals(csName))
                { 
                    PDFCosName csColorantName = csArray[1] as PDFCosName;
                    if ((csColorantName != null) && IsReplaceable(csColorantName.Value, colorantNamesToReplace))
                    {
                        csColorantName.Value = csColorantName.Value + suffix;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PDFCosDictionary resourcesXObjectDictionary = resourcesDictionary[PDFNames.XObject] as PDFCosDictionary;
    if (resourcesXObjectDictionary != null)
    {
        string[] xObjectIDs = resourcesXObjectDictionary.Keys;
        foreach (string xObjectID in xObjectIDs)
        {
            PDFCosDictionary xObjectDictionary = resourcesXObjectDictionary[xObjectID] as PDFCosDictionary;
            if (xObjectDictionary != null)
            {
                PDFCosDictionary xObjectResourcesDictionary = xObjectDictionary[PDFNames.Resources] as PDFCosDictionary;
                if (xObjectResourcesDictionary != null)
                {
                    SetColorspaceNameSuffixInResources(xObjectResourcesDictionary, colorantNamesToReplace, suffix);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static bool IsReplaceable(string colorantName, string[] colorantNamesToReplace)
{
    foreach (string name in colorantNamesToReplace) 
    { 
        if (name == colorantName)
        { 
            return true; 
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

The method `SetColorantNameSuffix` is called like this:

```
string[] colorantNamesToReplace = { "/Black", "/PANTONE Cool Gray 10 C" };
SetColorantNameSuffix("sample.pdf", "sample_replaced.pdf", colorantNamesToReplace, "_KM001");
```

Disclaimer: I work the company that develops PDF4NET.